# Converting list of stack images to time series files in R?

Tags: r, time-series, bfast

I am using bfast package for time series analysis. But it requires the files to be read as time series.

How to convert list of stacked images from 2000 to 2013 into a time series and given as input for analysis?

Comment: Your data needs to be of class "ts".  Take a look at the time series objects help page: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/ts.html

Comment: You should have a look at the example in `?bfastts` from the **bfast** package. It demonstrates the conversion of the first pixel of a 'RasterBrick' to a 'ts' object compatible with `bfast`.

Comment: i tried bfastts but im confused about what date i have to give for stack of one year data as my data is 8 day composite data..please suggest me

Answer (score 3):

You may want to explore the ["rts"](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rts/rts.pdf) package. It specifically coerces raster stacks into time series objects. Although, I do not know if they are compatible with bfast.

Your best bet would be to vectorize the problem in a function, passed to overlay, and use @Aaron advice by then coercing into a ts object. This is how I approach time series analysis of climate rasters.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey...but the problem has not solved.I am unable to create time series data of 8 day composite which can be given as input for bfast!

Comment: It would not be a very memory safe approach but, you could read the rasters in using readGDAL in rgdal. This results in a SpatialPixelDataFrame object where each time step is a column in x@data (time=column, pixel=row). You would then iterate through each row (pixel), coerce to a vector then ts object and pass it to the desired function in bfast. I should point out that ?bfast has a clear example of using NDVI data in a timeseries analysis with the function.